# Getting single element or throwing one of two exceptions

Tags: c#, collections, extension-methods, exception

Sometimes I need to get a single thing from a collection but I'm not very happy with the `Single` extension. It does not differentiate between empty and more than one element and throws the same `InvalidOperationException` in both cases. I find it's an important disadvantage and it helps a lot if you know excactly why and exception was thrown.

---

I want to *replace* it with my own extension that I currently name `Single2` as throwing two different exceptions.

```
public static T Single2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var count = 0;
    var single = default(T);
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext() && count++ < 1)
        {
            single = enumerator.Current;
        }
    }

    switch ((SearchResult)count)
    {
        case SearchResult.NotFound: throw new EmptySequenceException();
        case SearchResult.SingleMatch: return single;
        default: throw new MoreThanOneElementException();
    }
}

public enum SearchResult
{
    NotFound = 0,
    SingleMatch = 1,
    ManyMatches = 2,
}
```

The exceptions are very simple:

```
public class EmptySequenceException : Exception { }
public class MoreThanOneElementException : Exception { }
```

That's all. What do you think of this new helper? Is there still room for improvement?

---

**Example**

This is one of the methods that already uses the new `Single2`. It's from my `ResourceReader` and it searches for an embedded resource in an assembly.

```
public static string FindName<T>([NotNull] this IResourceReader resources, [NotNull] Expression<Func<string, bool>> predicateExpression)
{
    if (resources == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resources));
    if (predicateExpression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicateExpression));

    var predicate = predicateExpression.Compile();

    try
    {
        return
            resources
                .GetResourceNames(typeof(T).Assembly)
                .Where(predicate)
                .Single2();
    }
    catch (EmptySequenceException innerException)
    {
        throw DynamicException.Factory.CreateDynamicException(
            $"ResourceNotFound{nameof(Exception)}",
            $"Expression {predicateExpression.ToString().QuoteWith("'")} does not match any resource in the {typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name.QuoteWith("'")} assembly.",
            innerException);
    }
    catch (MoreThanOneElementException innerException)
    {
        throw DynamicException.Factory.CreateDynamicException(
            $"MoreThanOneResourceFound{nameof(Exception)}",
            $"Expression {predicateExpression.ToString().QuoteWith("'")} matches more than one resource in the {typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name.QuoteWith("'")} assembly.",
            innerException);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Spelling fix: It's 'more than', not 'more then'. I think that enum actually degrades readability a bit (the exception and variable names already provide sufficient information, and it's not like 0 and 1 are 'magic values' in this context), but other than that it looks fine to me.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thx, it's my favourite mistake. Always using _then_ instead of _than_, even though I actually know it's wrong, crap, I need to learn it once and for all :-] In the first version I actually had magic numbers but changed them first to `const` and eventually _upgraded_ to enums.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: using a custom base class for both exceptions would give you a little more flexibility: it allows you to also catch them together, for those situations where the distinction doesn't matter as much, without catching other kinds of exceptions.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I'd give you +1 if you wrote this as an answer ;-) It's definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really like the second `while` condition `count++ < 1` because IMO it is to hard to grasp at first glance when this condition really comes `true`.

I would do it without a loop but with simple `if` statements like so

```
public static T Single2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext() == false)
        {
            throw new EmptySequenceException();
        }
        var single = enumerator.Current;
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new MoreThanOneElementException();
        }
        return single;
    }
}
```

Now you don't have a `count` anymore hence no `switch` either. I have **not** used the `!` operator on purpose, because having two calls to `MoveNext()` in two different `if` condition one checking for `false` and the other for `true` harms the readability a little by using that operator.

Comment: This is a great suggestion ;-) and I'm on your side with the `== false`. It hurts readability here when you put `!` in front of the condition.